# Function call after updating the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, jsx

In this structure:

```
export const Parent = () => {

    function updateFn(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // do some action with the updated counter
    }

    return (
        <Child updateFn={updateFn} />
    )
}

export const Child = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

    function updateCounter() {
        setCounter(1)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={updateCounter}></button>
    )
}
```

what would be the best way to call `updateFn()` from within the `<Child>`, after the `counter` was updated, but with the same click? I need this because I am using the value of the updated counter in the `updateFn()`.

I have tried with a `useEffect` in the `<Child>` like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        props.updateFn()
    }, [counter])
```

but the problem with this is, first that it tries to call the function immediately on mount, which is not good because the counter is not updated, and second and most importantly, I get an error `Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` - if I comment out `preventDefault()` that will cause a refresh and that's also not good. As a side question, how can I call this from within the `<Child>` but also keep the `preventDefault()` behavior? If I would call this at the onClick event, without the brackets `()`, `preventDefault()` will work.

The solution that I found for this is to:

```
<div onMouseOver={() => setCounter(1)}>
    <button onClick={props.updateFn} />
</div>
```

While this is working, I think that this is not a very good approach, and I would like to learn the right way.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In the end, I've tried to use `useReducer()` as recommended in the comments and I'm updating the question with more details, pretty much changing the whole meaning and structure of it.

What I am trying to achieve is to control a popup from a wrapper component using `useReducer()` and send in the data that I want to display on the popup, calling the dispatch and using its payload from the children of this wrapper.

And on this popup, I usually have a button that needs to do different things depending on the child that opened the popup. Which ideally would take different functions that I would also like to send when I open the popup from the child.

As of now, my initial state of the reducer looks something in the lines of:

```
const [userActions, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, [
    {
        popup: false,
        valueToUseIn_someFn: "",
        action: new Function()
    }
]);
```

My first case to get the data looks something like:

```
case "get-data":
    return {
        ...userActions,
        ...action.payload,
}
```

And from the child I'm setting the action and open the popup like:

```
props.dispatch({
    type: "get-data",
    payload: {
            popup: true,
            valueToUseIn_someFn: someValue,
            action: function() {
                return someFn()
            }
     }
})
```

And once the popup is open, when pressing confirm button, I am calling the previously set function in a case like:

```
case "do-the-action":
    userActions.action()
```

This is working, `someFn()` is being called when I press confirm.

`someFn()` looks something like:

```
console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn)

function someFn() {
   console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn)
}
```

But the issue is that everytime I press Confirm the logging in the `someFn()` shows the previously set state:

if firstly the `someValue = 1` this will be:

```
//inside the child of the wrapper 
console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn) //returns1 

function someFn() {
   console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn) //returns undefined
}
```

if secondly `someValue = 2` this will be:

```
//inside the child of the wrapper 
console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn) //returns 2 

function someFn() {
   console.log(props.userActions.valueToUseIn_someFn) //returns 1
}
```

I have also logged the `userAction` object after being updated by the child and seems that all the data that I need is updated and available. It's just that `someFn()` does not take this current state, just the previously set one and so on.

So now I am more confused than ever, and I would really like to know why exactly this is happening and how could be repaired, what is wrong with this approach, and best practices for doing this.

Thanks again!

Comment: call `props.updateFn` inside `updateCounter`

Comment: There are many possible ways to solve this, and each solution fits for specific situation and level of code complexity. You can use *context*, you can use *render-props* method, you can keep the state in the parent-level and make it more complex if you have multiple counters (you can even use `useReducer`), you can also drill-down the `updateFn` callback to the child and then call it within the child whenever you need...

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722042/function-call-after-updating-the-state-in-react#comment123246751_69722146) . Thanks

Comment: @vsync it's not 100% clear how every concept you proposed works, but I will jump into each topic and explore more, thanks

Comment: @vsync after thousands of tries and a few things learned along the way, this particular thing I still couldn't solve. I've ended up using `useReducer()` but with no success. It has the same behavior, the first click always sends the previous data, while the second does the right thing. So the counter is always one step behind the function call - I'm not sure if this makes sense in these words but this is what's happening. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @labilouser - can you edit your question with an updated example? I don't understand what *"behind"* means because the `Child` counter is only setting its state in your current example to `1` and doesn't count afterwards

Comment: @vsync I have updated the question, hopefully, it makes more sense now. If you have some time, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a **very simple** *codesandbox* where I can examine your code and run it?

Comment: @vsync sure, here it is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-glade-ogg6f?file=/src/App.js). thanks again! let me know if something is not clear

Comment: so many mistakes... so many. your reducer has `get-data` & `do-action` - both are not things you put in a reducer, which is meant only for **setting** state and not getting state or executing callbacks. Also, state **must not** contain *functions*.  You are sending `dispatch` deeper and deeper, which is an anti-pattern in React, since you should use the `context` to access things at components which are deeper than direct children.. Also, you should not do `return dispatch...` because a `dispatch` is meant for  updating the state, and not to return anything. Work with the state & props only

Comment: Yea well it's the first time I'm trying to use reducer on my learning path so I was expecting this answer. I will change and take everything from scratch having your points in mind. thank you

Comment: I am now using Context, and everything seems to be working fine. How would you send the action that needs to be on the popup button from child to context provider if state must not contain functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside the `updateCounter` function as follow:

```
function updateCounter(e) {
  setCounter(1);
  props.updateFn(e);
}
```

Additionally, you can get the event paramter of the `onClick` in the `updateCounter` function and pass it to `updateFn` to be able to call `preventDefault` on that event.

Calling it in the `useEffect` with `counter` as a dependency will indeed excecute it on the first render. You could add an additional state variable to track if it is the first click or not and call `updateFn` depending on that, but it is still a complex solution for a simple problem. The solution described above should be enough.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original post that I've already tried this since it seemed logical. The problem that I have when using this approach is that counter doesn't get the value in the parent with the first click - as I said, I am using the counter value in the parent's updateFn. With the first click, the updateFn is triggered, but the counter is empty, with the second click, updateFn is again triggered and this time counter has the value of 1. I am using useCallback to get the counter to the parent. Any idea why this? Thanks

Comment: Use `setCounter(counter => { let c = counter +1; props.updateFn(c); return c; })`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thanks for this, but this is not working. It just sends the empty counter on the first click and on the second it sends the data.